# The GET method is not supported for this route using button to change status in Laravel

Tags: laravel, forms, post, get

i'm using laravel in my project , i got this error : The Get method is not supported .
I'am trying to change status of the patient when the doctor click on the button (Accepter) .
This is the Controller :

```
public function completedUpdate(Request $request, rendezvous $id)
{
     $data = rendezvous::find($id);
        foreach($data as $rdv) {
            if ( $rdv->Etat_de_rdv == 'en_attente' ) {
             DB::table('rdv')->where('Etat_de_rdv','en_attente')
          ->update(['Etat_de_rdv' => 'Accepter']);
         $data->Etat_de_rdv = $request->changeStatus;
     $data->save();
    }
}
return redirect()->back()->withSucces('rdv accepter' ) ;
```

This is the form :

```
@if($lo->Etat_de_rdv == "en_attente") 
                    <form action="{{ route('completedUpdate', $lo->id) }}" method="post">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}                          
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="changeStatus" value="Accepter">Annuler</button>
                    </form>                    
                @else
                    <form action="{{ route('completedUpdate', $lo->id) }}" method="post">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}                              
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="changeStatus" value="Charger">Accepter</button>
                    </form>                                                 
                @endif
```

the web.php :

```
Route::post('/completedUpdate/{id}', 'rendezv@completedUpdate')->name('completedUpdate');
```

Comment: i already change it but nothing change @DevinGray

Comment: See below the answer should help from